# How to set up 2 ethernet in Kbuntu?

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, netplan, nas

I have a problem setting up my network with ubuntu.
In my office we have several pc, and a NAS. Most of the PCs (all windows) connects to internet, and to NAS via 1Gbit ethernet, but mine has a direct fiber 10Gbits ethernet to the NAS plus the normal 1GB. I want to access to everything via 1GB, and to the NAS only by the 10Gbits.
I have windows working with both interfaces with dhcp.
I've  tried with the .yaml file and cant figure out what's happened.
I have internet so 1Gbit is working, but the fiber ethernet keeps in constant "connecting" until it fails
Thanks for your time
Claudio

PS: my our knowledge in linux is some kind of rooky.

edit to add details:

Kubuntu version: LTE 20.04

etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml looks like:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: yes
    enp9s0:
      dhcp4: yes
```

-Y tried separate in 2 files (01-xxx.yaml and 02-xxx.yaml)

-Tried "renderer: NetworkManager"

-Tried different online tutorials and everything looks quite similar, but the results are allways the same, got 1Gbit interface up but no 10Gbits running (10GBits interface works grate in windows, so no hardware issues)

-recuested `sudo lshw -C network`

```
-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 03
       serial: b4:2e:99:37:32:09
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.13.0-35-generic duplex=full firmware=0. 6-1 ip=192.168.0.125 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:37 memory:ba400000-ba41ffff ioport:2000(size=32) memory:ba420000-ba423fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82599 10 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: enp9s0
       version: 01
       serial: 80:61:5f:0d:e1:bb
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre 10000bt-fd
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=ixgbe driverversion=5.13.0-35-generic duplex=full firmware=0x80000707, 1.2074.0 ip=192.168.0.130 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes speed=10Gbit/s
       resources: irq:31 memory:b8000000-b807ffff ioport:1000(size=32) memory:b8080000-b8083fff memory:ba700000-ba77ffff memory:b8084000-b8183fff memory:b8184000-b8283fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: wlx8c882b005eba
       serial: 8c:88:2b:00:5e:ba
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=5.13.0-35-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Comment: We will need more details to be able to help you correctly like what version of Ubuntu are you using?  How is your yaml file configured?  Please add all of this to your question. More details will help us help you!  However, this can be done as it would be best to assign a static IP address to the 10Gbps interface without a gateway assigned to use the attached NAS.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1398552/edit) and add all the information asked in the comments.

Comment: Done, I have updated the post with some information

Comment: On your system with the 10Gbps interface can you run `sudo lshw -C network` and add that to your question?  It might need the proper driver installed for it.

Comment: edited question , added more information.

Comment: Do you know what the IP address of the NAS is?  Both your 1Gb and 10Gb connections are up and working.  But, they are on the same subnet (192.168.0.XXX) so the system is going to connect to the first one which is the 1Gb.  If the NAS is on the same subnet as both your NICs are there is actually no need for your 1Gbps connection at this time as it is just overkill.

Comment: NAS has several IPs, two of them has fiber and static IPs (192.168.0.50 and 192.168.0.51)

Comment: NAS has several IPs, two of them has fiber and static IPs (192.168.0.50 and 192.168.0.51).
My PC has 1GB used to connect to all the network and internet, and fiber direct to the NAS. Should we try with fixed IPs something like 192.168.0.XXX and 192.168.1.XXX??

Comment: I would go with the static IPs, but make sure that they are either reserved in the DHCP server or that they are outside of the DHCP range so that you don't get IP conflicts.  To separate it would be best to give only one subnet per NIC.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have two files in my /etc/netplan/ folder, one pero interface, and looks like this:
1Gb interface

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: yes
```

10Gb interface

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
   ethernets:
    enp9s0:
      dhcp4: no
        addresses: [192.168.0.130/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.151
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

I have take care of the spaces in every line, used `sudo netplan apply` and the result is more or less the same, I have internet and can connect to the local network but cant access the NAS. If I disconect 1Gb interface, 10 Gb works like charm, but I cant access internet or the local network.
What you think I am missing?

Comment: Hello. How is this an answer? You appear to be asking a question . If that is the case you do not do it in the answer to another question. If this is more info for the question already posted edit that question and add to it.

Comment: sorry I don't know the mechanics of the forum, I saw that couldn't write enough to explain in the comments so I thought that I could do that.